# What does it mean for a subatomic particle to "have" energy?

Tags: energy, subatomic

From my limited classical interpretation of the universe, i've always found it convenient to think of energy as what happens when an object isnt in its equilibrium position in the universe, and thus has some combination of the 4 fundamental forces acting on it to cause it to move to an equilibrium state.

So in terms of the subatomic world, when people say for example that an electron can be at different energy levels, does that mean that either the electron or its internal components are farther from an equilibrium position and thus more energy will be used when the forces act on the electron? Or does my interpretation of energy fall apart at this level?

My apologies if my lack of knowledge has caused me to pose the question in an ill formed manner.

I was just really wondering if the concept of energy works along the same principles at the subatomic level

Comment: The energy levels for electrons are just the potential energy of the proton-electron system(for an H atom, keeping it simple). So, there is a force.

Comment: Ok that's about as simple as i could hope for! But what about a single electron in a vacuum, not part of an atom. Can it still be said to have "energy"?

Comment: Sure it can, since "equilibrium" has not been defined. For instance, if your electron encounters a positron, the characteristics of the resulting photons is determined by the energy equivalence of the mass of the electron.

Comment: @user1299028 About a single electron in vacuum, you could give it kinetic energy, but the notion of equilibrium would not apply, as WhatRoughBeast pointed out. Also, the concept of potential energy would work when we have a 'system'.